# How to get response length before reading response from socket in java

Tags: java, sockets

I am working on MML server, my Task is to read response from MML server. In this case, there is no "End of Response" Character in response. How would i know that that response is ended? Is there any kind of technique to get response length before reading the response. by doing this i want to break my while loop using the response length.

```
while(true)
{
    try
    {
       char temp = (char) is.read();
       System.out.println(temp);
       responseLine = responseLine + temp;
    }
    catch(Throwable e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide any documentation of the response you're trying to process?

Comment: "`SC`00601.00PK001224CRBT1   00000001DLGCON    00000001TXEND     ACK:LOGIN:RETN=0000,DESC=LOGIN SUCCESS! E3EDF59D"

this is the response from MML while the end string changes time by time its not constant or fixed. response is ended on "D" last chararcter. but how do i know whats the coming response length. i want to break my while loop after reading the last character "D". and also the length of the response is also not constant.
Hope you got my point. Thanks alot

Comment: You need to study the MML protocol, whatever that is, to discover how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know MML, but with streams in general, the ways to recognize end of a message are:

- "end of message" flag / sequence in the stream
- a known message header containing information about message length - you then count the bytes / chars
- end of stream - the sender closes the stream on their end

Comment: problem is there is no end of message flag, and im try is.readShort() it return 2468 but chars in response is not not than 222 or 230 chars.